# Send a multi-select select's values on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, multi-select

In a form I have 2 `<select multiple>` elements. First one is filled with `<option>` itens in server-side.

I have then developed a JavaScript code to move itens from one to another. That's a basic multiselect feature.

Now I must send second select's values back to server when form is submitted. But it only sends itens that are selected. That's not the behavior I need, I want all existing itens to be sent. Any idea how to implement it, preferably without using Ajax?

Comment: Add a `submit` handler that marks all the options in the second `<select>` as `selected`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if user comes back to that page, he may see those itens selected.

Comment: Another option is to use hidden fields to hold the options from the second select.

Comment: hmm that's a good idea, create new fields for each value!

Comment: I agree with Barmar. Add a hidden field called "chosenOptions" or something. Add some javascript so that whenever an item is selected, you add it into the hidden field (with a separator character) and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not implementing it. But if I would I'd just try to get all select's values into an array, JSON marshal them and put the string into the input hidden. I'd try to do it in form's submit event.